# Amount of math research published in other languages?

Tags: soft-question, journals

I'm curious what languages contribute the largest fraction of published research mathematics. That is, for a given language the percent of new research being published in that language. I'm especially curious to see how you come up with such numbers.

From some googling I managed to get a very crude estimate of total publication volume: [28643 arXiv articles in 2014](http://arxiv.org/year/math/14). Looks like arXiv sometimes has articles in other languages but I can't search by language.

Edit: Thanks S. Carnahan for pointing out that I could search the full text by common words from different languages!

Comment: Don't forget that non-anglophone countries have repositories, too, for instance HAL (France), SciELO (Brazil/S. America more generally)

Comment: The claim "they're always in English as well" is only true of the abstracts, not necessarily for the articles.  As the page you linked indicates, if you search the comments for language words, you may get information about the article language.

Comment: Ah, great idea @S.Carnahan and thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question has no definite answer if time frame is not specified. The situation in 20s century changed very quickly. In the first half of the century, German and French dominated.
(More German than French). In the second half, it is clearly English, and one does not need any research to see this. But English dominates more and more. In the 1970-s and 1980-s about 1/3 of all papers was published in Russian. (I did count this. There was a Russian counterpart of Math Rev, using Cyrillic for Russian papers, so it was easy to count).
Not anymore. Until the late 70s, most German papers were published in German. Not anymore.
My guess would be that in 21st century an overwhelming majority of publications are in English, and there are some in French and Chinese. Proportion of other languages is negligibe.

EDIT. In the discussion, mostly arXiv is discussed, so you probably mean very recent papers. I follow the arxiv since its inception, and my impression is that less than
1% of all papers are written in French or Russian. I have not seen any in German or other languages, including Chinese.

EDIT2. One also has to specify what kinds of books and papers are we talking about. Of course, textbooks and lecture courses are published in every language. Because TEACHING in most countries is in the native language, especially undergraduate teaching. Same applies to many publications intended for more general audience, publications related to education and history, popular mathematics etc. In the arXiv they are in the sections "History" or "General math". All non-English papers on the arXiv that I know are in "History".
I will not be surprised if statistics from the arXiv will be very different from that in Mathscinet, even if one restricts Mathscinet to the recent years when arXiv exists. In fact arXiv is not a good representative for the whole mathematics. In some areas, almost all papers go to the arXiv, in other areas, only a small proportion.

EDIT3. OK, in Mathscinet they indicate the language:-) Since 2000:
70K in Chinese, 66K in Russian, 21K in French, 5K in Spanish and Japanese each, 4K in German and Italian each, 1K in Portuguese. Out of 1,358,623 total. Zentralblatt seems to have a similar feature but I could not make it work.

Comment: I would imagine Portugese and Spanish are present for South America. I don't know the quantities, though.

Comment: It is present, of course. See my EDIT2

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreEremenko this is an interesting answer. As you surmise, my interest is mostly in new content. If you could somehow estimate the fractions by language of historical content though, across all time, I'd love to see it. I don't think arXiv is representative but I couldn't find really any representative source. Here's an example of papers in Chinese: [papers on Acta Mathematica Sinica](http://www.actamath.com/Jwk_sxxb_cn/CN/article/searchArticleResult.do).

Comment: @Whosyourjay: Actually Mathscinet is a better source, if you restrict the year range. And has a much superior search possibilities.

Comment: Cool, this is a solid estimate of relative frequency for non-english language publications. I'm also curious if Mathscinet covers most of recently published papers. I notice that it has around 13x the content of arXiv for that time period, so maybe even more content is isolated in non-english journals.

Comment: Oops, only 7x the content.

Comment: The time lag in Mathscinet is few months, indeed. So if you really need the result for September 2015, just wait few months:-) The time lag between arxiv and publication is usually much larger.

Comment: What was the "Russian counterpart of Math Rev"? Has some of its content appeared online?

Comment: @Igor Khavkine: It was called "Referativnyi Zhurnal", and covered ALL science, not only mathematics. The coverage of math was as wide as MathRev and Zentralblatt. I have never seen any trace of it online, whether it is still published on paper, I have no idea.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine: It seems that it still exists: http://www.viniti.ru/pro_ref_el.html

Comment: Here is a German arXiv paper, for what it's worth: arXiv:math/0308287 . I am not aware of any other.

Answer (score 15):

I researched the language distribution using the Web of Science. Since your interest was in new content, I restricted the search to the period 1985-2015. The total number of mathematics articles in that database is 882565 for this period. Here is the breakdown by language:

[image]

### [1985-2015]

---

The Web of Science goes back to 1945, so I also made the search for the entire period 1945-2015. That gives a total of 1120170 mathematics articles, with this breakdown by language:

[image]

### [1945-2015]

---

Finally, for the last ten-year period 2005-2015 the breakdown (for a total of 459213 mathematics articles) is

[image]

### [2005-2015]

---

It is clear that the coverage of Web of Science is not representative for Asia, but for the European languages I would expect it to give a reliable breakdown.

Comment: Now I can't help but wonder what those two papers in Danish are.

Comment: Or the one in Latin (or the four in Welsh!)

Comment: Cool, and fascinating how different it is from @Alexandre's results.

Comment: @DavidRoberts ---  I'm afraid that the language detection algorithm of Web of Science is not completely reliable; the paper listed as being in Latin has a Latin title, but the text is in French (no idea what the author was thinking, but that's how it is).

Comment: Talking about papers written in Latin, I did have to struggle with that one: http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~schechtman/defin-nova-preprint.pdf

Comment: Web of science is not an appropriate database for Math. They do not even try to cover ALL journals, only those with high "citation rate" where the "citation rate" is determined from the same database.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko --- the coverage of Math journals in Web of Science was discussed in some details in this [_posting_](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41000/why-are-some-good-math-journals-not-indexed-by-thomson-reuters) --- it seems that the selection process is quite a bit more balanced than just counting citations, as explained [_here_](http://wokinfo.com/essays/journal-selection-process/) --- I do note that the selection process is balanced towards English language journals, which would explain the difference in the language statistics with MathSciNet.

Comment: I have to wonder whether the paper cited by André came about because the author wrote (or thought) the phrase "only classical objects" as in the summary, and decided it would be appropriate to write the paper using only a classical language.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Web of Science should not be considered a serious or useful database in Mathematics, because the whole mathematics is marginal in it. It is just not useful when we discuss mathematics.

Comment: @AndréHenriques Frankly, I've seen English articles much harder to understand. The amount of text in that article is practically negligible and high school level Latin without any revising is enough to understand it. But then in Italy we study Latin for 5 years in high school, which may be significantly more than in any other country.

Comment: I find it suspicious that Japanese is conspicuously absent from all the lists, when it is tied with Spanish in Alexandre's list. Does WoS not have a category for Japanese? Then again, Chinese is also significantly underrepresented compared to Alexandre's data, so perhaps WoS is more Euro-centric. (Oddly enough, the selection process link is translated into ten European languages, plus Japanese (but not Chinese), even though there are apparently no Japanese articles in the database.)

Comment: If I remember well, Clifford Truesdell who founded *Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis*, decided that the accepted languages would be English, French, German and **Latin**. He himself wrote a paper in Latin !

Comment: @DenisSerre Yeah, I remember seeing that paper by Truesdell in Latin. I didn't try to read it. I wonder if he had much trouble finding a referee for it, or if he refereed it himself.

Comment: @bof Since he was the editor (and founder), Truesdell did not need a referee.

Comment: The paper of Schechtman written in Latin, cited above, seems reasonably comprehensible to me despite not knowing Latin.  (I am a native English speaker; I can read French and some Spanish.). It is a bit strange seeing a paper in Latin that takes the "definition-theorem-proof" form of a "modern" math paper.

Comment: The Schechtman paper is in the proceedings of a conference, and is described as "linguistically refreshing" in the introduction (https://books.google.com/books?id=JLCP9gaXTEoC&pg=PR12&dq=%22linguistically+refreshing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH-YPA16_gAhVuh-AKHQPTCT0Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22linguistically%20refreshing%22&f=false) - from the table of contents we see that most of the papers were in English, with one paper in French.

Comment: @DenisSerre I know it was his journal. That's what I meant by "refereed it himself". I wasn't sure what the ethical requirements are for the editor of a respectable refereed journal to publish a paper in his own journal.

Comment: Counting periods such as 1945-2015 is a bit unfair since the volume has considerably increased in recent years (and also the ratio volume/quality). Including shorter periods such as 1945-1955, etc, would provide much more interesting indications.

Comment: @bof I have never been editor-in-chief of some journal, but I presume you are right. The case of ARMA is however special, as Truesdell founded it after having been sacked from the journal he founded previously (Indinana UMJ). He wrote the whole story, perhaps in issue #100 of ARMA.